# Carto (editor): how to disable hoverwindow -temporarily- on different layer

Tags: carto, infowindow

See example https://designink.carto.com/viz/e6b1b7c5-ebc9-4a1f-8b8d-d63f127983ca/public_map

I have an active infowindow on a specific layer (Spain) -with active url as text inside-, but this conflicts (overlaps) with the underlying hoverwindow of another specific layer (France). How can i disable the underlying hoverwindow -temporarily- when this infowindow is active?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done with CARTO Editor. You need to use CARTO.js. [Here](https://carto.com/academy/courses/cartojs-ground-up/) you can learn how to use this Javascript library from the ground up. Basically, you would need to disable the interactivity of the fields after the click event. Then, after closing the infowindow you would need to set the interactivity again.